# DateTime value changed, fetching from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, reactjs, momentjs

I stored the `datetime` value in database using `toISOString()` `{10-01-2017 00:00:00}`.
While retrieving the original date it is reduced by `05:30` minutes where date`{09-01-2017 18:30:00}`

Comment: I would guess that there is some sort of timezone conversion happening?

Comment: You are, almost without doubt, located in India. The 5:30 offset is the giveaway. You stored your datestamp in India Standard Time, and retrieved it in UTC. If you [edit] your question to show the definition of your MySQL table, maybe we can help you sort out how to get more predictable behavior.

Comment: Holiday{name(string),day(string),date(datetime),id(integer)}